# Convert an ImageData object (not a canvas) to image dataURL

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, base64, data-uri

I would like to create a dataURL from an ImageData object (i.e. width, height, data). I realize canvas has this, but I want to avoid distortions canvas use has (alpha premultiply mainly) .. i.e. I want to avoid the obvious canvas.putImageData step.

From [this post](https://coolaj86.com/articles/typedarray-buffer-to-base64-in-javascript/) I can make any arraybuffer/typedarray/dataview into base64. What I *dont* know is how the canvas dataurl adds the width/height to the Uint8 data portion of the base64 string. Nor do I know how the png conversion is done. (I'd be OK with a raw data image type but I don't think there is one .. just png and jpg)

Possible approaches:

- Load ImageData into Canvas with putImageData. Fails, distorts data.
- Create an image with img.src = base64 data. Fails, has to be canvas dataurl.
- Other?

Anyone know how to construct an image dataURL from the raw width, height, data Imagedata?

Answer (score 5):

It is theoretically possible, but not practical, to convert an `ImageData` object to a `data URL` without using a `Canvas`.

An `ImageData` object has the raw RGBA representation of the image pixels. A `data URL` expects data to be in a recognized `MIME` format. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#Image_types), the only widely supported pixel-based image types are GIF, JPEG, PNG, and ICO. GIF and JPEG are quite complex, all of these formats have header information, and PNG has a CRC, so it is non-trivial to convert the pixel data into the image format.

The recommended way to do the conversion is using the `Canvas`. You say your attempts "distorted" the data, but that suggests there was something wrong with how you did it, since that is really the best supported method as it builds on the internals browsers use to do all their image manipulation.

Did you check your `context` settings? You probably want `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"` instead of the default `"source-over"` if you are using alpha.

Comment: Thank you. I need to make this operation server side. I currently use the [package `canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) but I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: The main distortion comes from alpha pre-multiply for non-255 alpha values. Secondly, any browser based approach can have "color profile" adjustments. I have since found a rather easy webgl approach which involves using framebuffers. I should make a gist of it!

Comment: Isn't BMP a more straightforward format to convert Uint8ClampedArray data into? It's supported by all major browsers.